# How to force Entity Framework to generate separate WHERE clauses?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, partitioning

I have a partirtioned table and I use it via entity framework.

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PART_FN (NVARCHAR(10))
AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES ('CASE0');

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PART_SCH
AS 
PARTITION PART_FN
ALL TO ([PRIMARY]);

CREATE TABLE TEST_PART(ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ON [PRIMARY] IDENTITY, COL2 NVARCHAR(10), COL3 NVARCHAR(10))
ON PART_SCH(COL2);

DECLARE @C INT = 1000000;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT TEST_PART ON;

WITH
A AS (SELECT 1 AS N
UNION ALL
SELECT N+1 FROM A WHERE N < @C)
INSERT INTO TEST_PART(ID, COL2, COL3)
SELECT ID, COL2, COL3 FROM(
SELECT N AS ID,
'CASE' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), CASE WHEN N%20 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS COL2,
'D' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), N, 0) AS COL3 FROM A) AS A
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT TEST_PART OFF;
```

I run two selects:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_PART WHERE COL2='CASE0' AND COL3='D240';
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM TEST_PART WHERE COL2='CASE0') AS A WHERE COL3='D240';
```

They look the same.
But!
FIRST has execution plan with degree parallelism 4 and estimated subtree cost ~5
SECOND has execution plan with degree parallelism 1 and estimated subtree cost ~2.5

If I use IQueryable like

```
query.Where(test=>test.COL2 == "CASE0")
    .Where(test=>test.COL3 == "D240")
```

EF concatenates where clauses and generates query like FIRST.
Is it possible to force entity framework generate query like SECOND?

PS: I use EF 4.4 and MSSQL 2008 R2

Best regards,
Roman

Answer (score 0):

When you don't want to use generated SQL of entity framework based on your linq, you can use these options:

1. Change your linq query, unfortunately this won't help in your specific scenario.
2. Use low level entity framework queries called *EntitySql*, but this won't help you too.
3. Use your own SQL, but don't loss benefits of change tracking, object materialization and other benefits of entity framework

To do this you can use this code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var appDb = new AppDb())
            {
                var peopleFromCustomQuery = appDb.People.SqlQuery("select Id , Name  from People");

                // OR

                peopleFromCustomQuery = appDb.Set<Person>().SqlQuery("select Id , Name  from People");
            }
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }

        public String Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class AppDb : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    }
```

And finally I recommend you to use latest version of entity framework, which generate sql queries far better than it's previews versions.

Good luck